# option strict conversion errors

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I just switched my project to "option Strict" to try to improve performance since I am experiencing some issues related to project speed.

I have received many errors; many were easy to fix by giving string conversion operands however this one I cant figure out

```
Option Strict On disallows operands of type Object for operator '='. Use the 'Is' operator to test for object identity.
```

This error is specifically targeting the Case target numbers 
such as

Case **0**

Case **1**

Case **2**

3

4

5

6

```
    If utable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        pop = 0

        For pop As Integer = 0 To utable.Rows.Count - 1
            TempStr(0) = CStr(utable.Rows(pop)("UID"))
            TempStr(1) = CStr(utable.Rows(pop)("lname"))
            TempStr(2) = CStr(utable.Rows(pop)("fname"))
            TempStr(3) = CStr(utable.Rows(pop)("uname"))
            Select Case utable.Rows(pop)("Usertype")
                Case 0
                    TempStr(4) = "Restricted"
                Case 1
                    TempStr(4) = "Dispatcher"
                Case 2
                    TempStr(4) = "Dispatch Supervisor"
                Case 3
                    TempStr(4) = "Contract Specialist"
                Case 4
                    TempStr(4) = "Account Billing"
                Case 5
                    TempStr(4) = "Manager"
                Case 6
                    TempStr(4) = "Administrator"
            End Select
            TempStr(5) = CStr(utable.Rows(pop)("Usertype"))
            TempNode = New ListViewItem(TempStr)
            Dim Add1 As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(TempNode)
        Next
    End If
```

I am not familiar with how to fix this any help is appreciated

Comment: Case Is 0, Case Is 1, etc?

Comment: changes error to "Relational operator required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this should do it:

```
Select Case CInt(utable.Rows(pop)("Usertype"))
    Case 0
        ...
    Case 1
        ...
End Select
```